# Login into application via different credentials from different systems opens the same dashboard of a User (duplicate)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

This issue appears very rarely , we tried it 100 of times manually in two systems.

Can Anyone Plz help me in replicating this Scenario, it is just like ---Login into Gmail from Two Systems with different Credentials at same time ..

But both of the Inbox belong to a single user (duplicate)....

I tried it via Selenium Parallel Browser Test : and Iterated the Script for more than 15 times ....

But Issue not replicated :

What could be the reasons for this issue  , If anyone have faced it so far..?

It is replicated at client end , and said that it occurs in a difference of .5 second .....then why it is not getting caught via selenium

Comment: What do you mean by iterated the script? How many threads are you using? Why not test this directly at the code level instead of going from the UI level?

Comment: I mean - I created a TESTNG script to open the Login page in two browsers(chrome,Firefox) in parallel.......and than via XML i tried to ran this script ...number of times , in order to replicate the scenario.  .......................I am not allowed to work with application code ...i have to replicate it from the UI ...as a user......Do you have any idea ..what it could be in code level .....

Comment: Guessing it could be a thread synchronization problem in the code. Try using more number of threads concurrently to open more browsers. St thread count to the number of processors you have. (Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()) Maybe use only Chrome or firefox at one time.

Comment: Selenium opens a clean browser instance each time it runs so it may be some caching issue?